# Struggling with Get.Component and Destroy

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Hello everybody so my program is quite a simple one,what i'm trying to do is do have to objects and destroy one of them by pressing either H for hero or E for enemy damage is random but i made it very close so they go down quickly , non the less i can't seem to figure it out after hours of trying and googling please help, because it's still not working :( 
So the first script is placed in the both objects i have a cube named Hero with a Tag named Hero as well,and the second object is a sphere with the name Enemy and with the same name of the Tag.

This is the script they both own :

```
public class Character : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float HP = 100;
    public float minDmg = 23f;
    public float maxDmg = 25f;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {

    }
    public float DamageDealt()
    {
        float damage;
        damage = Random.Range(minDmg, maxDmg);
        return damage;
    }
}
```

And the second script is placed onto the camera which should be fine i think ?

```
public class FightControl : MonoBehaviour
{
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        GameObject _hero = GameObject.Find("Hero");
        GameObject _villain = GameObject.Find("Enemy");

        //object se pravi da bi moglo da se preuzme var iz Character u obkejtu _hero
        Character chscript = _hero.GetComponent<Character>();
        //object se pravi da bi moglo da se utice na hp u objectu _villain
        Character chscripta = _villain.GetComponent<Character>();
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.H))
        {

            float dmg = chscript.DamageDealt();



            chscripta.HP = chscript.HP - dmg;
            if (chscripta.HP <= 0)
            {
               Destroy(_villain);
            }
        }


        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.E))
        {
            Character chscript1 = _villain.GetComponent<Character>();
            float dmg1 = chscript1.DamageDealt();

            Character chscript1a = _hero.GetComponent<Character>();
            chscript1a.HP -= dmg1;
            if(chscript1a.HP <= 0)
            {
                Destroy(_villain);
            }


        }


    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: By "not working" what do you mean? Does the code fail to compile? Please describe what is occurring here.

Comment: It does compile,but no result.

Answer (score 2):

Your second script is not working because you are running everything only once.

The Start() method runs only once once the game object has been enabled. You are reading input during the start method, but not during any other frames.

Consider moving some of your code to the Update() method so that you are reading the input every frame:

```
    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.H))
        {
            float dmg = chscript.DamageDealt();
            chscripta.HP = chscript.HP - dmg;
            if (chscripta.HP <= 0)
            {
               Destroy(_villain);
            }
        }


        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.E))
        {
            Character chscript1 = _villain.GetComponent<Character>();
            float dmg1 = chscript1.DamageDealt();
            Character chscript1a = _hero.GetComponent<Character>();
            chscript1a.HP -= dmg1;
            if(chscript1a.HP <= 0)
            {
                Destroy(_villain);
            }
        }
    }
```

Rather than finding the game object during runtime, you could consider creating a reference and configuring the hero/villain references by dragging the gameobject to the inspector after making this change to your code. You can do this for both Components and GameObjects, so with the following code you should have 4 "slots" in your inspector:

```
public class FightControl : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject _hero;
    public GameObject _villain;
    public Character chscript;
    public Character chscripta;
//... the rest of your code (the Update() method above)
```

Comment: I will try this in the morning !

Comment: @StefanKefi Also, this line does not look right: `chscripta.HP = chscript.HP - dmg;` You're setting the villain's HP to the hero's current HP minus the hero's damage (`chscript` vs `chscripta`! Use intelligent variable names!).